# Does Mass Effect 3 feature a violence or language filter option?

Tags: mass-effect-3

From what I've heard and seen, there is a decent amount of violence and language in this game. I'm referring to things like headshots bursting in a spray of alien blood and some off-color words uttered casually in dialog.

**Is there an option to tone down these occurrences for those who do not wish to experience them or those with younger children?**

Comment: The simplest option would be to buy a game that does not contain relentless slaughter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mass Effect 3 is intended for adults and is justifiably rated **M - Mature**.  It does have plenty of dirty words and violence.

There is not an option to censor this content, no.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

There is no option to restrict the content of the game on moral grounds.